# Datapager always marks page 1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, datapager

I'm facing a problem with two Datapagers associated with a Listview. This is my page:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="PagerTop" runat="server" PagedControlID="pp" QueryStringField="page" PageSize="30"></asp:DataPager>

<asp:ListView ID="pp" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="holder" EnableViewState="true" OnPagePropertiesChanging="PagePropertiesChanging">
...
</asp:ListView>

<asp:DataPager ID="PagerBottom" runat="server" PagedControlID="pp" QueryStringField="page" PageSize="30"></asp:DataPager>
```

and the code behind is as follows

```
Private Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    Dim MyData As List(Of Product)
    MyData = ResultsManager.GetResults()
    pp.DataSource = MyData
    pp.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub PagePropertiesChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs)
    PagerTop.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, False)
    PagerBottom.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, False)
    pp.DataBind()
End Sub
```

When I change the page, the listview is updated and shows the results corresponding with the indicated page, and `PagerTop` shows the selected page. That's how they are supposed to work. But `PagerBottom` is stucked on page 1 and never changes!

It doesn't matter which pager I click, `PagerTop` always works and `PagerBottom` always stays at page 1.

I'm running out of brilliant ideas... what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a very good example is given here 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/datapager-in-Asp-Net-3-5/
just place another data pager with different id without any change. i have tried and worked fine for me.